# parameterized top clause query in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-4.0, ado.net, parameterized-query

I want to use the top clause query in C#

```
objConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionstring"].ToString());
            objConnection.Open();
            objCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP (@perpage) * FROM user_master", objConnection);
            objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@perpage",objusmspass.strperpage);
            objReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

I am getting object reference not set to the instance of the object at line

```
objReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

Thanks,

Comment: Add _sql_ related tags to your question.

Comment: @Aristos I checked none of my values are null. My other functions are also using the same method and they are working fine. Is there some problem in my query or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your either custom object objusmspass & its property is null or not, Use try catch blocks to see what kind of exception it is (sqlException or other than that)

Comment: I checked none of my values are null. My other functions are also using the same method and they are working fine. Is there some problem in my query or something.

Comment: Did u add try catch block(s) ? What type of exception is getting caught?